# Add on scroll header effect / transition with position property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a header which `position:absolute` on load I need to display it fix on particular scrolling so it working ..

but problem is that how I use header effect (i.e display with delay from upward) with `position:fixed` property.

code:

CSS

```
.iaw-header {
    position:absoulte
}
```

JS:

```
{
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {
       jQuery('.iaw-header').css('position','fixed');
    });   
}
```

Comment: Please place your code in the post, and don't use a shortener. Makes the link suspicious.

Comment: I think you mean `position` when you're saying `display`.

Comment: @pablopixel yes position sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    Header text here.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header { position: absolute; }
```

JS

```
if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {
    $('#header').css('top', '-300px'); 
    $('#header').css('position', 'fixed'); 
    $('#header').animate({top: 0}, 1000);
} else {
    $('#header').animate({top: '-300px'}, 1000, function () {
        $('#header').css('top', 0); 
        $('#header').css('position', 'absolute'); 
    });
}
```

So when the site loads (in CSS), the header can have `top: -300px;`, and when the user scrolls, you transition (or set) the header's top to 0px, so it scrolls down from the top.

Comment: no bro, I need it absoulte on top position when its scroll down at 700 then its fixed its all are working I am just confusion in header effect

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: BUt now header is fixed from start , but we need it to show on fix at 700 , below this it should be normal..

Comment: What do you mean by "normal"?

Comment: in absolute position.

Comment: have you checked the link?

Comment: If you have a specific question or error, post your code and ask for help. This isn't a site for people to do your work for you.

Comment: Do you know about the `setTimeout()` function?

Comment: yes but will it effect on show() and hide() function , can I use it with position ???

Comment: Did you try it? If it doesn't work, ask a new question and put your code in it.

Comment: yes I tried  `setTimeout(function () { jQuery('.iaw-header').css('position','fixed'); }, 500);`    But not working

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    var i = $('.iaw-header')
    var h = i.outerHeight(true);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > h) {
        if (!i.hasClass('fixed')) i.hide().addClass('fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 400) {
        i.slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        i.removeClass('fixed').show();
    }
});
```

Add a class in your style:

```
.fixed {position: fixed;top:0; left:0;width: 100%; }
```

Perhaps, not the best code but still you can start building on it and modify to make it better. Here is the Jsfiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/gxRC9/200/

Comment: Its working for I am just asking about header effect like that http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/16/on-scroll-header-effects/

Comment: at 700 when it position fixed so it should appear with effect from up to down with delay

Comment: @AliRaza Code updated. Please check it works for you.